# Let's register that Django user

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, authentication, django

#### Short intro

So, I've been using Django for a while now and thought it would be nice to start a simple application. In an ideal World, each app *must* have a way of letting its users register and that's what I'm gonna do below.

---

#### Description

I've used the [latest Django version](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) for this project -> because of this, I couldn't use [`django-registration`](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.4.1/) module as it's incompatible with the above. Apart from this, I've used Python 3.6.5.

What I want to do it's common along other web applications:

1. The user goes to the registration page and fills in the following fields:

- `first_name`
- `last_name`
- `email`

2. The user submits the form and receives a confirmation email with an URL containing a unique token.
3. When the user clicks on the received link, he's redirected to a page where he'll set his password.
4. When done, he's logged in to the dashboard page.

---

#### Code

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    A custom user manager to deal with emails as unique identifiers for auth
    instead of usernames. The default that's used is "UserManager"
    """

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email must be set')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a regular User with the given email and password.
        """

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True, max_length=64)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email
```

---

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.forms import ModelForm

User = get_user_model()


class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

---

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash, get_user_model, authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, SetPasswordForm
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_text
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, View

from .forms import RegistrationForm
from .tokens import account_activation_token

User = get_user_model()


class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'base/home.html'


class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'base/login.html'
    form_class = AuthenticationForm


class CustomLogoutView(LogoutView):
    template_name = 'base/login.html'


class RegistrationView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        registration_form = RegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'base/register.html', {'form': registration_form})

    def post(self, request):
        registration_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if registration_form.is_valid():
            user = registration_form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.set_unusable_password()
            user.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your account.'
            message = render_to_string('base/activation-email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = registration_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()

            return render(request, 'base/confirm-email.html')


class ActivationView(View):

    def get(self, request, uidb64, token):
        try:
            uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
            user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            user = None

        if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
            login(request, user)

            form = SetPasswordForm(request.user)
            return render(request, 'base/password-set.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            return render(request, 'base/verification-failed.html')

    def post(self, request, uidb64, token):

        try:
            uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
            user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            user = None

        form = SetPasswordForm(user, request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)

            user = authenticate(username=user.email, password=form.cleaned_data['new_password1'])
            login(request, user)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, form.errors)
            return render(request, 'base/password-set.html', {'form': form})
```

---

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .views import (
    CustomLoginView, CustomLogoutView, HomeView, 
    RegistrationView, ActivationView
)

app_name = 'apps.base'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),

    url(r'^login/$', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', CustomLogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

    url(r'^register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(), name='register'),
    url(r'^confirm_email/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base/confirm-email.html'), name='confirm_email'),
    url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        ActivationView.as_view(), name='activate'),
]
```

---

**tokens.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils import six


class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) +
            six.text_type(user.is_active)
        )


account_activation_token = TokenGenerator()
```

---

#### Things that I'd like to be reviewed:

- Django Design Patterns: Did I use the correct views / forms / models in my app? Should some of the logic be written somewhere else etc...
- Security: Is my register system secure? If not, what can I do to make it so?
- General feedback: Anything that comes to your mind is welcome (including criticism, ideas, improvements, cats...aliens..)

Comment: It could be worth putting your code and templates in a public repo for people to clone, to make it easier to review